# Google Storage - get actual link without redirection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage

Suppose I am uploading an image to Google Storage using Go SDK

It gives me an URL like https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucketname/filename/

When I click to that link, it redirects me to the full link that contains the image like the below, how can I get this link when I upload the image ?

I just want to get the direct URL of the image to be used in the production, like profile image.

https://00f74ba44be8acc17bae10cd4adcfd29cdd8652b78-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o/1662407444441829_366660_441897186_9530049184352?jk=AFshE3WObOtQpfkxfrdvi4TDLKWpXBjin-1thaaiNNW3GfLnMmc87SSkTdWouwBtEYZmHywUzCvBHJuzT6hKR37fZRqnOaFm8CFp5Kxf1s12x3GQ0LrDv8AzM5x_yhoxncFiNwlNYJs9JWtk9zHQv0kVw-prfYLL7TCm3EZ3uk5KT1EIqe4RHlbjsiuA1IKOiAtbILDBAqlhUa1U32o_VH1_Y2-RHihycqXWlkTuqYjjiVJUCiuhHNMN0db3tWUw5B9N9BIb8LViEgdB5MOB4eD5gzJLDVcHCIRAmQcSXjo0hHbo6bs7-E35UwOlZE00Yv568KVZG1YOdYZpaFK610r9zWoJjNHDYuLedgekJqayteEudl-vffb9OC0IlECXBL-nWHVbXuyBHgNIqGAw3Z-qBLeXJ_ZhA8XFbI8wuQjaQAm1bS_TnlCx8a6qKiJsxZRT0cf6GK9aCTcMsvgv9Pyfz5TxJPFtbwWcncx0BNAOu3bel7kxmv223xAmZ7JnC0P8J-ba78f4c4Vh8vSYjOkz2gyJBiWnajhrmD3wJ_2d_0zPAjnZ0UlkTxhVfKhrShNC27ARyo4Qk3XTz_u85ExpGTdONYM8wLf0rzs5AA4ofheQqih6mDDkH7rOZAomPqyEmIH_U_qmRUoMyW3gWObjbK7WPqv49UJa_POn2c5YDqeF5AYjspp_MFKarhTN-qlFDPKfZuHk5gdpYyn12qnValEy-ezqPR0AKb0CrxCGLHR_rUWcF21HePybY80xQlyHAKAwz4cyQOv7UwvZ9WiK3TUtWQjSSDYEiMX0oaGGZjl3jYmQWRkfZzoJ0w86MbBuknW41xRIwfj_WBSM04ChxmDCnFuYoBi-wUhyKzadwQygJyTgmbLO4jTVEn_wT66df3EDxAMtp-Y5VgYF1Z9vUBp56OMm7zAS70KjQXNhom10EZsjpMyBw23pvEqdi2hK2ygITOVuMOYs3f2Rc6LCpkg_x2Fn5U6ZfHap7n_f5DVGEHVWZTFygX0RcH58Hjt8w-3bHTpd9a8o_G6YoZdsWiOM32uRBOsnfDfuNGpBIF1PWEtx2RopISOvama6JOEmzEW3YV1DO-3-SLwUygAAjFR3YyGKfKztc0FvKG9RDG4sDVw&isca=1

Comment: Your content seems cached. What's the problem with that redirect?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere the thing is that I want the use the url in the production as images like profile image or post image, so it has to be a direct jpg or png url, not a url that redirects to the file

Comment: My bad. look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the public URL instead: https://storage.googleapis.com//

The url in cloud.google.com requires authentication.